# Which filters or actions to use after a media upload and delete?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, images, wp-filesystem

When a media (image) is uploaded and the subsequent images are created (all the different sizes), I would like to perform a few actions. It is simple and I basically need only the new attachment ID, that would be enough.

Same during deletion: before or after deletion, I need to know which attachment ID is concerned.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i guess you are looking for this

`add_attachment`

and

`delete_attachment`

example:

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'attachment_manipulation');
function attachment_manipulation($id)
{
  if(wp_attachment_is_image($id)){
    //do your own tasks
  }

}
```

Comment: and don't forget edit_attachment (in case you care if the image is rotated or scaled after being added)